# CSS - Make parent & Child div's equal height

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to create looks like this:

```
 --------------------------------------------------
 |                        |           |           |
 |                        | .box1     | .box2     |
 |                        |           |           |
 |   .image               -------------------------
 |                        |                       |
 |                        |     .description      |
 |                        |                       |
 |                        |                       |
 --------------------------------------------------
```

Where the .box1 and .box2 will be the same height compared to eachother (f.e. `flex: 1;`) and the image and the shell around .box1, .box2 and .description the same size as well.

I just can't seem to find a way that does exactly this, I figured Flexbox examples are rare for this case.

I thought a table would work for this example, having a nested table like the following:

```
<table class="parent-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="image">
      <img src="...."/>
    </td>
    <td class="parent-box">
      <table class="child-wrapper">
        <tr>
          <td class="box1">.box1</td>
          <td class="box2">.box2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <!-- I don't know a workaround for this as well -->
          <td class="description" colspan="2">.description</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

But this turns out like the following:

[image]

What I want is that the 'image' td is sized to be the same height as the 'child-wrapper' td

So this: (made with hardcoded heights)

[image]

Comment: Its working fine.

Comment: Tables should only be used for tabular data - not for layout (unless this is an email template)

Comment: To echo what @Pete said, tables are for tabular data. For better semantics and WCAG (web accessibility) compliance it'd be better to switch to divs and use a flexbox for layouts where possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flexbox example:

No need for a table for this!

Edit: Updated to match requirements. Play with the (shorthanded `flex-basis`) `20%` and `min-width` of `250px` on `.image` to fit your taste. Note that I set the background image through style as I assume it will come from a back-end.

Perhaps you also want a min-height on your main container.

```css
.block {
  display: flex;
}

.image {
  flex: 0 1 20%;
  min-width: 250px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}

.image img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
}

.boxes {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
}

.box1 {
  background: cyan;
  flex: 1;
}

.box2 {
  background: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}

.description {
  flex: 1;
  background: #531777;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="image" style="background-image: url('https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/c8/e8/cc/c8e8cc83e6eeb60061ba11c9d8ba9a11.jpg')">
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="boxes">
      <div class="box box1">
        .box1
      </div>
      <div class="box box2">
        .box2
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="description">
      .description
      <br>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut mollis sed augue eu pulvinar. Cras sodales tortor ac mauris bibendum, quis sagittis quam viverra. Aliquam erat volutpat. Pellentesque ullamcorper porta metus, nec efficitur lorem vulputate quis. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Aenean vel dui et eros gravida bibendum. Nunc pulvinar commodo facilisis.
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/LRgwOy

Comment: Now the problem here is that the 'content' class is getting stretched, although I want the 'image' class to depend on the height of the 'content' class. (now they depend on eachother, but I want to overflow the image)

Comment: @Ivaro18 so you're okay with the width of `.image` being flexible (with the image keeping its ratio)?

Comment: yes, the image should keep its ratio, this is an example image of a building but the normal image would be more of a pattern where the contents are centered, but I already have the css for that

Comment: @Ivaro18 Is the image always the same ratio?

Comment: Probably not but the css for the img doesn't really matter, Just trying to position the image-div with the height of the `content`.

Comment: It does matter. What happens if you have an extra tall image with very short content, like so: http://codepen.io/veksen/pen/rrqXRx Would you want the image the scale down? I'm asking because it gets rather complex there, so if I don't know/understand your complete requirement, it's hard to help you =) In this case, the height of the image will always push the height of the box.

Comment: exactly, that is my problem, the image will push the height of the box. I want to have the box kind of 'depend' on the height of the `div.content`. So that if `div.content` is a height of 500px (based on content). That the `div.image` is also 500px (while image could be 800px). (image will overflow the div)

Let me show you in the question what I want f.e.

Comment: So you're ok with the image cutting off?

Comment: Yes it should cut off, and I already have the css for having the center of the image show instead of f.e. the bottom

Comment: Yes! thanks for taking the time to understand the request :)

Comment: For some reason when using this in Angular 2, the description box will be positioned *over* the .box1 and .box2

Comment: @Ivaro18 are you sure you're using the equivalent of my `.boxes` container? I suspect your markup differs from mine.

Comment: Its even worse, I create a normal `.html` file, and it works perfeclty, now in my localhost with angular, removing every single script, rewriting the body and the head with the contents of the `.html` file, and the description is still over the `.box1` and `.box2`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126094/discussion-between-veksen-and-ivaro18).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```css
.parent-1 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.parent-2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-basis: 400px;
  height: 250px;
}
.box-2 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(38, 60, 99);
}
.box-3 {
  flex-basis: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(185, 195, 28);
}
.parent-3 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-1">
  <div class="box-1">
    <img src="img-1.jpg" alt="img" width="200" height="200">
  </div>
  <div class="parent-2">
    <div class="parent-3">
      <div class="box-2"></div>
      <div class="box-3"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="box-4">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to include colspan in your td with description.

```
<td class="descrtiption" colspan="2">.description</td>
```

http://codebeautify.org/htmlviewer/cbea20ae

Answer (score 0):

Check the code below.. you will get some idea..
Result screen-shot of code below

[image]

```css
table{
width:100%
}
table, th, td {
   border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding:5px;
}
th, td {
  padding:35px;
}
```

```html
<table class="parent-wrapper">
  <tr>
    <td class="image" rowspan="2">
      Image
    </td>
    <td class="box">
      Box
    </td>
    <td class="box">
      Box
    </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
    
    <td class="box" colspan="2">
      Description
    </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: What do you want exactly?

Comment: As you can see, the 'child-wrapper' td is resizing to the img's height, but I'd want the 'image' to resize to the height of the 'child-wrapper'

Comment: the reason is you are using nested table... best practice is to write single table and avoid nesting...

Comment: best practice is not to use a table